# Why does this empty <option> in ng-options clear all selections?

Tags: angularjs

I have a plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/OoVxgsGm7L0ytHIJXaTm?p=preview) to demonstrate.

I am using a blank option tag in my ng-options select.

```
    <select ng-model="food.fruitOne"
        ng-options="fruit.id as fruit.name for fruit in fruits | filter: food.fruitTwo && {id: '!' + food.fruitTwo} | filter: food.fruitThree && {id: '!' + food.fruitThree}">
       <option value="">-</option>
    </select>
```

The select list is used 3 times for 3 different ng-models.  Strangely, if you make a selection from any of the choices and then change that selection back to the blank option all 3 choices switch to the blank option and the selects all crap out.

Interesting.  In [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/iduBwP9AdSWr2lbaSbvd?p=preview) plunk which does not use the filters, the selects don't act that way.  Clearly the filter is the culprit.  Why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is error in yours filter in `ng-repeat`.

See updated [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/72rQmFjBybhLzw2Z3Ly1?p=preview)

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.food = {
    fruitOne: "",
    fruitTwo: "",
    fruitThree: ""
  };
  $scope.fruits = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'apple'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'banana'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'orange'
  }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <label>Choice 1</label>
  <select ng-model="food.fruitOne" ng-options="fruit.id as fruit.name for fruit in fruits | filter:food.fruitTwo!=''?{id: '!' + food.fruitTwo}:{} | filter:food.fruitThree!=''? {id: '!' + food.fruitThree}:{}">
    <option value=""></option>
  </select>
  <label>Choice 2</label>
  <select ng-model="food.fruitTwo" ng-options="fruit.id as fruit.name for fruit in fruits | filter: food.fruitOne!=''?{id: '!' + food.fruitOne}:{} | filter: food.fruitThree!=''?{id: '!' + food.fruitThree}:{}">
    <option value=""></option>
  </select>
  <label>Choice 3</label>
  <select ng-model="food.fruitThree" ng-options="fruit.id as fruit.name for fruit in fruits | filter: food.fruitOne!=''?{id: '!' + food.fruitOne}:{} | filter: food.fruitTwo!=''?{id: '!' + food.fruitTwo}:{}">
    <option value=""></option>
  </select>
  <hr>
  <p>Choice 1 - {{ food.fruitOne }}</p>
  <p>Choice 2 - {{ food.fruitTwo }}</p>
  <p>Choice 3 - {{ food.fruitThree }}</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Correct!  Thanks.  Sorry for the delay is noting this as the answer - had moved on to something else for a bit.

Answer (score 1):

`ng-options` and `option` does not work together.

You need to use only one of them. **Both of them do not work together in the same directive.**

The best way to add some particular values is to have it included in the **model**. For that you will need to customize your filter. That's how I did it in project.

Change your model to this:

```
$scope.fruits = [
    {id: 4, name: ' '},
    {id: 1, name: 'apple'},
    {id: 2, name: 'banana'},
    {id: 3, name: 'orange'}
  ];
```

Comment: Ok, so what would be the solution to add a no value option to my ng-options?  I need to give the use a chance to unselect something as the filter that removes chosen options is a requirement.

Comment: The best way is to have it included in the list. For that you will need to customize your filter. That's how I did it.

Comment: Any chance of an example?

Comment: just insert that hiphen in your model `food.fruitOne`

Comment: @RushVan Check the edited answer. Are you looking for something like this?

Comment: Well in the app my ng-options is actually pulled from a table not statically declared like in the plunk. So, I think your suggestion of a filter to add the first value/option is the direction I need to go.

Comment: @RushVan If that answer helped can you please accept the answer?

Comment: Doesn't unfortunately.  Check the plunk with the filters.  With blank {{ }} it still craps out.  Also, I thought your feeling was ng-options and option won't work together - isn't that whats being used if I add blank {{ }}??

Comment: @RushVan But it works for me. https://plnkr.co/edit/yEsDOzOcTHvoZOpYP498?p=preview

Comment: Try that again.  The original issue remains.  Make a selection and the re-select the blank option. Breaks all three.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://plnkr.co/edit/yEsDOzOcTHvoZOpYP498?p=preview

Comment: No.  While yes, adding a blank option to the model does give us a blank option to work with, the problem is selecting the blank option after selecting anything else is breaking the 3 selects all together.  That's my original issue/question.

Comment: @RushVan Try this : https://plnkr.co/edit/yEsDOzOcTHvoZOpYP498?p=preview

Comment: @RushVan Did you try that?

Comment: I did.  It does work but is not really what I need.  I need a option that is not getting filtered that has no value.  Your solution can actually be selected and therefore gets filtered out of the other lists.  I am trying a different approach now.  Thanks for the help.